# How to access value of clicked object after click event in JQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once the List is clicked, "active" class will be added to the list.. And once the class "active"  is added, I want to store the  values ( data-value and data-filter) to filter obj.

Problem: "active" class is added on click. On second click I can get the value of previously clicked => active class, not on same click. How can I solve this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidebar-filter').on('click', function(event) {
    /**$('.sidebar-filter').addClass("active");*/
    event.preventDefault();
    var filterobj = {};
    $(".sidebar-filter").each(function(index, ele) {
      var filterval = $(this).data("value");
      var filterkey = $(this).data('filter');
      // ('li[data-filter=' + filterkey+'].active')).map(function(el){
      filterobj[filterkey] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li[data-filter=' + filterkey + '].active')).map(function(el) {
        /**return $(el).data("value");*/
        return $(el).data("value")
        /** return el.getAttribute('data-value');*/
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="network" data-value="9">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="network" data-value="1">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="network" data-value="2">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="signal" data-value="9">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="signal" data-value="1">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items " data-filter="signal" data-value="2">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and DOM access in a very messy way. Use one or the other. I tried to make you a [mcve] - please add relevant HTML and IDs

Comment: What is your exact goal? If you're just trying to read the data attributes from the clicked element then your code is far more complex than it needs to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery as it was designed:

Assuming the UL has the class="sidebar-filter", then delegate and map

```js
$(function() {
    $('.filter-items').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    const filterobj = $(".filter-items.active").map(function() {
      return { value: $(this).data("value"), filterKey: $(this).data('filter') }
    })
    .get()
    .reduce((acc,cur) => {
      const key = cur.filterKey;
      if (acc[key]) acc[key].push(cur.value)
      else acc[key] = [cur.value];
      return acc
    },
    {})
    console.log(filterobj);
  });
});
```

```css
li a { text-decoration: none }
li.active a { text-decoration: underline }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-filter">
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="network" data-value="1">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="network" data-value="2">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="network" data-value="3">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="sidebar-filter">
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="signal" data-value="4">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="signal" data-value="5">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
  <li class="thread-filter filter-items" data-filter="signal" data-value="6">
    <a href="#">name</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the support, For single unordered list it worked exactly what I intended for. I tried to learn different ways for two `UL`. I wrote this messy snippet. how can I achieve this if I have two list in separate unordered list as shown on shared snippet(updated)?

This is the exact problem I could not solve.

Comment: What is the `.sidebar-filter` ?

Comment: My code works for more than one UL - see update

Comment: On my snippet you can see data filter are different for each UL

{network: Array(3), signal: Array(3)}
network: [9,1, 2 ]
signal: [4,5,6  ]

This is the expected output

Comment: No I cannot. You have 9,1,2 and 9,1,2 and you never told us expected output

Comment: 9,1,2, these numbers are id only. The thing is Both UL have different data filter. I tried to achieve that way and tried to obtain on json format but it did not worked. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: See update. I hope that is what you want